# Error when updating Stripe: Trait 'CRM_Core_Payment_MJWTrait' not found

Tags: stripe

I have just updated Stripe to version 6

It requires a Data Base update

But when I run this update, I get :
[Error: Upgrade com.drastikbydesign.stripe to revision 5023]
Error 1: Trait 'CRM_Core_Payment_MJWTrait' not found in /home/bapaparoisse/www/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/CRM/Core/Payment/Stripe.php, line 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a new requirement listed in the [Stripe CiviCRM documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/stripe/en/latest/) for version 6.0.  You also need the [MJWShared](https://civicrm.org/extensions/mjwshared) extension.